# Pidgin > New conversation window issue

Tags: windows-vista, pidgin

When I receive a new conversation I have it minimized so that it flashes 3 times 
then stays highlighted. Unfortunately after a while this taskbar button stops being highlighted.

Ive also noticed that when closing a browser (while still not clicking the minimized conversation) the taskbar button appears to not be highlighted anymore.

This is frustrating as Id prefer it to be highlighted until I have clicked it to inspect the new message. Its possible I could forget I have a new message apart for noticing the system tray.

Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Other than via replacing your shell or OS?

Comment: haha yeah, nothing as drastic as that! Im using Windows Vista.

Comment: Not a fix, but the tray icon will keep the new message symbol until you check it.

Comment: @Emory Bell > Thanks this appears to be the only notification thats permanent until you view the message with pidgin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows XP you can use the TweakUI tool to change the default behavior of the flashing. 
You can modify the registry manually, or seek out a tweaking tool to do this for you.

```
Run Regedit
```

Go to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Control Panel -> Desktop
```

Look for the "ForegroundFlashCount", double click it and change to 0. See my screen shot below.

[image]

I realize you want to keep the button highlighted and not flashing, but there aren't any options that I know of that do that.  Also be aware that this change is "system wide" for your user and not specific to Pidgin.

Comment: Thanks steve.lippert , seems this is the only option that can solve this! I will look into it.